# increment frequency of objects created in a loop

Tags: java, frequency

I am trying to create objects using some strings generated by parsing a file and
I need to increment the frequency of the object every time the string appears in the file again

```
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length - (k-1); i++) {                        
String s = "";
for(int j = i; j < i + k; j ++ ){
    s += chars[j];                  
}
if(!s.contains("N")){
    TreeObject obj = new TreeObject(s, 4);
    if(lines.contains(s)){
        obj.incrementFrequency();
        System.out.println("duplicate detected " + s + "\n");
    }
    else {
        lines.add(s);                                   
    }
```

where lines is a Set

```
Set<String> lines = new TreeSet<>();
```

I cant think of a way for doing it .. Since the data can be huge, I think that using an array wont be a good approach ...

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

```
Map<String, Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<>();
```

Then each time you get a new string `s` from parsing:

```
frequencies.put(s, frequencies.getOrDefault(s, 0) + 1);
```

This checks if an entry with key `s` already exists in `frequencies`, and if it does, adds 1 to its value. Otherwise, it just puts new entry with key `s` and value 1 into `frequencies`.

If you don't have access to Java 8, the solution is less elegant:

```
Integer previous = frequencies.get(s);
frequencies.put(s, previous == null ? 1 : previous + 1);
```

Comment: why do I get "the method getOrDefault is undefined for the type Map ......"

and how is HashMap different from TreeMap ?

would this work if I replace the string with another object ?

Comment: @H.K Are you using Java 8?

Comment: @H.K HashMap and TreeMap both implement the Map interface, so you can use whichever one you wish. HashMap is just easier to use and (usually) faster. This solution will work if you use a different type instead of String.